# Spark ItemRenderer not showing contents

Tags: list, apache-flex, itemrenderer, flex-spark

I have a spark list component and a corresponding custom `itemrenderer`:

list component:

```
<s:List id="albumImagesList" itemRenderer="the.namespace.for.XYZImageRenderer" useVirtualLayout="false" width="400" height="160">
    <s:layout>
        <s:TileLayout requestedColumnCount="5"
                requestedRowCount="2"
                rowHeight="80"
                columnWidth="80"
                horizontalGap="0"
                verticalGap="0" />
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

item renderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                autoDrawBackground="true" width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
    </s:states>

    <s:BitmapImage source="{data.image_path}" width="70" height="70" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" />

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

It's all fine and dandy, the data gets populated correctly and I verified that the `data.image_path` property arrives safe and sound inside the `itemrenderer`.

My only problem is: the image is not displaying. I am not sure if it doesn't render at all or if it's just not visible somehow.

Does anyone see something at first glance? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? I worked with mx item renderers before and I never had so much trouble with those.

Comment: At first glance everything seems fine. I suggest you to place <s:BitmapImage source="real_image_path" width="70" height="70" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" /> at your components mxml, to check wether image is loaded properly i.e. image_path is valid in your case.

Comment: i checked all this and the path is valid, the data arrives there and it is only that stupid bitmapimage element causing trouble... BUT: see my supposed answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phew, ok got it fixed using this guy's approach:
http://polygeek.com/2452_flex_extending-spark-bitmapimage

maybe it's going to be of help for someone.

cheers!

Comment: Yeah, Dan Rocks.  But why all this effort to use BitMapImage instead of just Image?  If you feel this is the best answer, be sure to mark it as such.

Comment: you're absolutely right. i just got carried away on trying not to use halo components anymore. don't ask why. i'd happily mark the good answers but it seems that my reputation is horribly low.

Answer (score 0):

after a little bit of fumbling and checking i suppose this is the answer to my question. maybe someone can confirm this, but i think it is pretty much spot on:

the "bitmapimage" can only load data from trusted (crossdomain-policy'ed) domains. so with local files it is no problem, but i was loading remote images and with that the bitmapimage silently shuts down and does nothing. no get request, nothing.

the old "image" can load stuff no matter where it originated and so i am now switching to this as a solution.

Comment: The CrossDomain policy relates to the Flash Player and is not applied differently to each class.  Image should have the same access limitations that BitMapImage does.  IF you have proof otherwise, I'd love to see it.

Comment: yeah, f**k me, that was too early... same problem there. and here comes the extra workaround hour.

Answer (score 0):

[BitMapImage.source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/BitmapImage.html#source) expects one of three things.  To quote from docs:

- A Bitmap or BitmapData instance.
- A class representing a subclass of DisplayObject. The BitmapFill instantiates the class and creates a bitmap rendering of it.
- An instance of a DisplayObject. The BitmapFill copies it into a Bitmap for filling.

It sounds like you're giving it a URL location.  If so, then use an [Image](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Image.html), not BitMapImage.

Comment: yeah, i got it all messed up. image is for loading, bitmap for embedding or publishing bitmapdata.